# Why I can't find my uri in Web Api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my PUT code in Web Api. (ASP.NET MVC 6).

```
    public class VendorManagementController : ApiController
   {
    // GET 
    [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public dynamic GetVendors(string sidx, string sortOrder, int page, int rows,int pkey)
    {

        var vendors = _vendorRespository.GetAllVendors().AsQueryable();
        var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        var pageSize = rows;
        var totalRecords = vendors.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        if (sidx != null)
        {
            vendors = sortOrder == "asc" ? vendors.OrderBy(sidx) : vendors.OrderBy(sidx + " descending");
        }
        else
        {
            vendors = vendors.OrderBy(x => x.pkey);
        }
            vendors = vendors.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        return new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (from vendor in vendors
                    select new
                    {
                        cell = new string[]
                        {
                        vendor.pkey.ToString(),
                        vendor.Company,
                        vendor.ContactName,
                        vendor.ContactPhone,
                        vendor.UserName,
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(vendor.UserKey),
                        vendor.Active.ToString(),
                        vendor.FacilityId.ToString(),
                        vendor.ClientID.ToString(),
                        vendor.PhotoURL,
                        vendor.PushToGP.ToString()
                        }
                    }).ToArray()
        };
    }
```

In the view, I have:

```
jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid({
            url: API_URL + 'GetVendors',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['pkey', 'Company', 'ContactName', 'ContactPhone', 'UserName', 'UserKey', 'Active', 'FacilityId', 'ClientId', 'PhotoURL', 'PushToGP'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'pkey', index: 'pkey', width: 50, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Company', width: 120 },
                { name: 'ContactName', width: 110 },
                { name: 'ContactPhone', width: 120 },
                { name: 'UserName', align: "right", width: 90 },
                { name: 'UserKey', align: "right", width: 120, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Active', width: 50, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, unformat: aceSwitch },
                { name: 'FacilityId', align: "right", width: 100, formatter: "integer" },
                { name: 'ClientID', align: "right", width: 100, formatter: "integer" },
                { name: 'PhotoURL', align: "right", width: 80 },
                { name: 'PushToGP', align: "right", width: 80, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, unformat: aceSwitch }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: pagerSelector,
            sortname: 'company',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            jsonreader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records:"records"
            },
            caption: "Vendor Managerment"
        });
```

However I inspect the page, I find a 500 error. See the image.
[image]

And in Home Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult VendorManagement()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        // Add the following to the request pipeline only in development environment.
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // Add Error handling middleware which catches all application specific errors and
            // send the request to the following path or controller action.
            app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        // Add static files to the request pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I am new to ASP.NET Web Api. Is there anything wrong on my mapping? Why I get 500 error?

Comment: First of all `GetVendors` supports only `GET` requests. Then where is your WebApi route config?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code and step through it. This will give you more details about what the problem is. 500 (Internal Server Error) doesn't tell you much on its own.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, I don't follow you. Do you mean that I have to add the similar code as `[Route("api/[controller]")]` before the controller?

Comment: If your controller is inheriting from `ApiController` base class, there should should be a `WebApi` specific route as well.Similar to your MVC one?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, so I replace `ApiController` with `Controller`, is it okay? But I still see the url in the browser is `http://localhost:54673/Home/VendorManagement` instead of `http://localhost:54673/Home/VendorManagement\GetVendors`.

Comment: @AndyNichols, I set a breakpoint. Yes, there is an exception, It is not routing issue at all. I was told that it is serialization and deserialization issue for byte array. Basically look at `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(vendor.UserKey)`, `UserKey` is a varbinary type in the database.

Comment: Have you tried moving `.ToArray()` so that vendors is returned from the DB before you create the anonymous type. Something like `rows = vendors.ToArray().Select(vendor => new { cell = new string[]{ vendor.pkey.ToString(), etc. } });`. I suspect the ORM doesn't know how to deal with it so it's better to return the data and let the code transform the data.

Comment: @AndyNichols, that line is just fine. I use [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server) to cache the data. The exception was there.`vendorList = CouchbaseManager.Instance.Get<List<Vendor>>(key);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data), it requires following default JSON format,

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

If I understand your code correctly then your method should return JSON result

Please try to modify code like this and see if it helps,

I have added **id = vendor.pkey**

```
    var result = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (from vendor in vendors
                select new
                {
                    id = vendor.pkey,
                    cell = new string[]
                    {
                    vendor.pkey.ToString(),
                    vendor.Company,
                    vendor.ContactName,
                    vendor.ContactPhone,
                    vendor.UserName,
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(vendor.UserKey),
                    vendor.Active.ToString(),
                    vendor.FacilityId.ToString(),
                    vendor.ClientID.ToString(),
                    vendor.PhotoURL,
                    vendor.PushToGP.ToString()
                    }
                }).ToArray()
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```